# Mouseover not working live, works in preview

Tags: html, css, mouseover

I have been working on a very simple thing for a while now, everything looks and works just fine when I just view the file locally. I used dreamweaver and dreamweavers preview works just as well in both firefox, IE and chrome.

My home0.png is supposed to change to home1.png when on mouseover and that's happening when viewed locally.

I uploaded all the files to a temporary host, and all is working except for the mouseover function. On mouseover is shows an error image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY4az.jpg]

I have split the image above in three parts;
The above part is what is doing live, when hosted

The middle parts is what is is supposed to do and what is is doing in DW preview and when viewed locally on my pc.

The third part is the code I used.

Can anyone spot the fault?

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: <div id="home"> 
        <a href="home.html" ><img src="IMG/HOME0.png" onmouseover="this.src='IMG/HOME1.PNG'" onmouseout="this.src='IMG/HOME0.png'" alt="HOME" /></a>
        </div>

Comment: Whoops. Is this sufficient?

Comment: you are using images for the diffrent background colours?

Comment: Probably the non-relative path - prefix your image paths with `/`

Comment: Edit the answer and put the code here, you can add path to your image and file where you include the image

Comment: Are you sure it's .PNG? Not .png ?

Answer (score 2):

If your file structure is something like:

```
-views
      -index.html
      -file2.html
      ....
 -IMG
      -HOME0.png
      -HOME1.png
```

you must add / to your img path:

```
/IMG/HOMEx.png
```

> **TIP:** Set better the name of files and folders to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part

```
onmouseover="this.src='IMG/HOME1.PNG'"
```

to this:

```
onmouseover="this.src='IMG/HOME1.png'"
```

Just change .png from uppercase to lowercase